# Ansible couldn't resolve module/action 'community.general.xml'

Tags: xml, ansible, xml-parsing, runtime-error, ansible-galaxy

I wish to use ansible's `community.general.xml` module to parse an xml.

The ansible playbook host (runner) is a docker container offered by OLAM EE Environment (Oracle Linux Automation Manager) that is not with my team.

I tried to install community general inside the playbook before utilizing the `xml` module like below.

```
    - name: Install general
      shell: ansible-galaxy collection install community.general
      become_user: root
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: installgeneral
 

{
  "changed": true,
  "stdout": "Starting galaxy collection install process\nProcess install dependency map\nto see the full traceback, use -vvv",
  "stderr": "\u001b[1;35m[WARNING]: Skipping Galaxy server https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/. Got an\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;35munexpected error when getting available versions of collection\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;35mcommunity.general: '/api/v3/plugin/ansible/content/published/collections/index/\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;35mcommunity/general/versions/'\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;31mERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: '/api/v3/plugin/ansible/content/published/collections/index/community/general/versions/'\u001b[0m",
  "rc": 250,
  "cmd": "ansible-galaxy collection install community.general",
  "start": "2024-01-28 08:57:19.687034",
  "end": "2024-01-28 08:57:20.569548",
  "delta": "0:00:00.882514",
  "msg": "non-zero return code",
  "invocation": {
    "module_args": {
      "_raw_params": "ansible-galaxy collection install community.general",
      "_uses_shell": true,
      "warn": false,
      "stdin_add_newline": true,
      "strip_empty_ends": true,
      "argv": null,
      "chdir": null,
      "executable": null,
      "creates": null,
      "removes": null,
      "stdin": null
    }
  },
  "stdout_lines": [
    "Starting galaxy collection install process",
    "Process install dependency map",
    "to see the full traceback, use -vvv"
  ],
  "stderr_lines": [
    "\u001b[1;35m[WARNING]: Skipping Galaxy server https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/. Got an\u001b[0m",
    "\u001b[1;35munexpected error when getting available versions of collection\u001b[0m",
    "\u001b[1;35mcommunity.general: '/api/v3/plugin/ansible/content/published/collections/index/\u001b[0m",
    "\u001b[1;35mcommunity/general/versions/'\u001b[0m",
    "\u001b[0;31mERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: '/api/v3/plugin/ansible/content/published/collections/index/community/general/versions/'\u001b[0m"
  ],
  "_ansible_no_log": false,
  "_ansible_delegated_vars": {
    "ansible_host": "localhost",
    "ansible_port": null,
    "ansible_user": "olamuser",
    "ansible_connection": "local"
  }
}
```

As a solution i tried installing with  `--no-cache` and it worked successfully like below but the `xml` module still errors:

```
---
- name: Get DB details from tomcat xml
  hosts: your_target_host
  environment:
    ANSIBLE_COLLECTIONS_PATHS: "/runner/requirements_collections"
  tasks:
    - name: Install general
      shell: ansible-galaxy collection install community.general --no-cache
      become_user: root
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: installgeneral
      
    - name: Get DB details from tomcat xml
      include_tasks: "{{ playbook_dir }}/extractfromxml.yml"
      vars: 
        xmlpath_rec: "{{ xmlpath_rec }}"
        DBname: "{{ DBname }}"
    
    - debug:
        msg: "INSTALLGENERAL: {{ installgeneral }}"
```

cat extractfromxml.yml

```
---

- name: Extract DB details from XML
  community.general.xml:
    path: "{{ xmlpath_rec }}"
    xpath: "/Server/Service/GlobalNamingResources/Resource[@name='{{ DBname }}']"
    content: text
  register: db_details
```

Output:

```
{
  "msg": "INSTALLGENERAL: {'changed': True, 'stdout': \"Starting galaxy collection install process\\nProcess install dependency map\\nStarting collection install process\\nDownloading https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/v3/plugin/ansible/content/published/collections/artifacts/community-general-8.2.0.tar.gz to /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-125pzia2sj6/tmpgs0_jwew/community-general-8.2.0-xv57fqkm\\nInstalling 'community.general:8.2.0' to '/runner/requirements_collections/ansible_collections/community/general'\\ncommunity.general:8.2.0 was installed successfully\", 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'cmd': 'ansible-galaxy collection install community.general --no-cache', 'start': '2024-01-28 09:19:41.413594', 'end': '2024-01-28 09:19:45.208997', 'delta': '0:00:03.795403', 'msg': '', 'stdout_lines': ['Starting galaxy collection install process', 'Process install dependency map', 'Starting collection install process', 'Downloading https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/v3/plugin/ansible/content/published/collections/artifacts/community-general-8.2.0.tar.gz to /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-125pzia2sj6/tmpgs0_jwew/community-general-8.2.0-xv57fqkm', \"Installing 'community.general:8.2.0' to '/runner/requirements_collections/ansible_collections/community/general'\", 'community.general:8.2.0 was installed successfully'], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False}",
  "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
  "_ansible_no_log": false,
  "changed": false
}

TASK [Get DB details from tomcat xml] ******************************************
fatal: [remotehost]: FAILED! => {"reason": "couldn't resolve module/action 'community.general.xml'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.\n\nThe error appears to be in '/runner/project/tomcat_templates/extractfromxml.yml': line 3, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Extract DB details from XML\n  ^ here\n"}
```

I tried to list and check if the `community.general` was installed properly as below:

```
- name: LIST general
  shell: ansible-galaxy collection list -p /runner/requirements_collections
  become_user: root
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: listgeneral

- debug:
    msg: "LISTGENERAL: {{ listgeneral }}"
```

Output:

```
{
  "msg": "LISTGENERAL: {'changed': True, 'stdout': '\\n# /runner/requirements_collections/ansible_collections\\nCollection        Version\\n----------------- -------\\nansible.posix     1.5.4  \\ncommunity.general 8.2.0  ', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'cmd': 'ansible-galaxy collection list -p /runner/requirements_collections', 'start': '2024-01-28 09:56:18.101264', 'end': '2024-01-28 09:56:18.484268', 'delta': '0:00:00.383004', 'msg': '', 'stdout_lines': ['', '# /runner/requirements_collections/ansible_collections', 'Collection        Version', '----------------- -------', 'ansible.posix     1.5.4  ', 'community.general 8.2.0  '], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False}",
  "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
  "_ansible_no_log": false,
  "changed": false
}
```

Can you please suggest why am i not able to use xml module despite installation?

Sample tomcat server.xml:

cat /web/bea_apps/uat/Tomcat_Home_v9.0.56/TomcatNode01/conf/server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8048" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
          <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

    <Resource auth="Container"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        global="dsCanweb"
        name="dsCanweb"
        password="P5jYL3yhwMF_Ep8P"
        username="CAN_WEB_USER"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@MYHOST36db06v.mybc.com:1521:DB01"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        initialSize="15" maxTotal="150" maxActive="100" maxWaitMillis="10000" minIdle="15"
        accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="90000"
        logAbandoned="true" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="7200"
        removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true"
        jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer;SlowQueryReport(threshold=600000,logFailed=true)"
        testWhileIdle="true"
        validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
        validationInterval="30000"
        testOnBorrow="true" />

    <Resource auth="Container"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        global="canwebds"
        name="canwebds"
        password="RMbbgwfxt2Os_2024"
        username="CANADA_WEB_USER"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@MYHOST36DB06V.mybc.com:1521/oltt206"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        initialSize="15" maxTotal="150" maxActive="100" maxWaitMillis="10000" minIdle="15"
        accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="90000"
        logAbandoned="true" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="7200"
        removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true"
        jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer;SlowQueryReport(threshold=600000,logFailed=true)"
        testOnBorrow="true" />

</GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="12408" address="uswl1212myb01.MYHOST35as28v.mybc.com" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="12409" />

<Connector port="12404" address="uswl1212myb01.MYHOST35as28v.mybc.com" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="12409" requiredSecret="QmtmM3hWcEVzUW5VTDNLdQo=" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="worker8">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className='org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve'
                showServerInfo='false' />

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: I do not see any XML on you posting.  Error looks like you do not have permission to access the Route "module/action".  I suspect it is a credential issue.  Are you using Windows Credentials or OAUTH2.  Errors like this often occur because to the credentials. associated with the Route.

Comment: @jdweng shared sample server.xml for tomcat server that i m trying to parse.  i m unaware of any credentials issue which i also feel is not. I have root access of docker container offering ansible using OLAM (ansible tower). I m able to create any folder or perform all tasks in the docker container as i have root access. Like from the output you can also see that i was able to install pakages collections to docker container on OLAM.

Comment: The Route is the PATH.  See 4 & 5 at : https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-root-application

Comment: @jdweng my issue is using the ansible xml module in ansible and not to do with the xml file. I will wait for more inputs.

Comment: Try troubleshooting and check the server logs : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Troubleshooting+and+Diagnostics

Answer (score 1):

> The ansible playbook host (runner) is a docker container offered by OLAM EE Environment (Oracle Linux Automation Manager) that is not with my team.

From [`community.general.xml`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/xml_module.html) docs:

> You might already have this collection installed if you are using the `ansible` package. It is not included in `ansible-core`.

So basically the main issue is that your execution environment seems to be incorrect because it likely has only `ansible-core` installed instead of `ansible`.

> As a solution I tried installing with `--no-cache` and it worked successfully like below but the xml module still errors

If your EE is a Docker container then most likely you run a fresh instance every time. And Ansible is not able to dynamically load the collections (e.g. when the playbook is already running). See [Ansible source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/13e6d8487a2fb93779da64e15018ae0a0f48a2c4/lib/ansible/parsing/mod_args.py#L331) for details.

The only correct solution I see is to properly prepare the execution environment - either install the whole `ansible` package or install all the required collections separately.

EDIT: I've just created a test playbook that uses a collection that I don't have installed:

```yaml
---
- name: Get DB details from tomcat xml
  hosts: localhost
  environment:
    ANSIBLE_COLLECTIONS_PATHS: "runner/requirements_collections"
  tasks:
    - name: Install general
      shell: ansible-galaxy collection install servicenow.servicenow --no-cache

    - name: Try to invoke a ServiceNow task
      snow_record_find:
        username: ansible_test
        password: my_password
        instance: dev99999
        table: incident
        query:
          assignment_group: d625dccec0a8016700a222a0f7900d06
        return_fields:
          - number
          - opened_at
```

When I run this playbook Ansible validates the tasks and returns an error even *before* running any of them:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yaml 

ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'snow_record_find'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/Users/alexander/IdeaProjects/stackoverflow/77894304/playbook.yaml': line 10, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


    - name: Try to invoke a ServiceNow task
      ^ here
```

Having these tasks in two separate plays makes no difference.
Ansible (at least as of core version 2.16.2) checks for available collections before running the playbook.

Comment: from the output can you confirm that `community.general 8.2.0` got installed ? and if so why cant i use the `xml` module in ansible?

Comment: Let me rephrase my concerns. Seeing that a collection is installed by Ansible itself does not mean that Ansible can use it. My assumption is that by the time of installation Ansible has already bootstrapped all the collections so it can't use anything that has been installed after that.

Comment: so that would imply that we cannot install any ansible packages and use them on the fly. I have in the past installed packages like community.general or posix explicitly and used a few years after my initial ansible setup.

Comment: can i have 2 plays i.e `hosts`  entries .... in the first i install the collection and in the second i use it so as to fullfil my requirement? So within the playbook run i can install a new collection as well as use it ? is that possible?

Comment: No it's not possible. I've updated my answer with an example and provided a link to Ansible source code.

Comment: thank you ... could you share some material that helps me setup EE for OLAM as i have never done that before?

Comment: I didn't do that either - I usually prepare my own images using Dockerfile.
If you already use EEs, then most likely you have an existing environment definition somewhere in your organization and adding one collection would be something straightforward. Otherwise I'd recommend to start with the [official documentation](https://ansible.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started_ee/index.html)