# How do I install and use an Ansible collection within an AWX playbook at run time?

Tags: testing, ansible, ansible-awx

Firstly, I'm new to AWX (like very new!) so this is probably something very simple, but just beyond my ability to solve.

I'm currently writing a playbook to run in AWX to test whether a host has been deployed correctly (I'm aware of the idempotency, etc of Ansible, but we have a requirement to demonstrate test coverage).

My problem is simple, I have a playbook which I'm using to test a Windows VM. I want to retrieve a list of the installed Windows updates. I know I can use the win_updates collection (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_updates_module.html), but I cannot seem to get it to install.

I've tried using:

```
roles:
  - role: ansible.windows.win_updates
```

Alas this hasn't worked and I'm not able to use a requirements.yml file (and don't rightly know how in the context of the playbook).

Any help would be good as I'm finding the ansible/AWX documentation particularly useless.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible couldn't resolve module/action 'community.general.xml'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77894304/ansible-couldnt-resolve-module-action-community-general-xml)

Comment: And also I cannot agree on calling the documentation useless because for any module there's an explicit note on the top that says if it's included in `ansible`/`ansible-core` package, how to install the collection, and what the dependencies are.

Comment: `ansible.windows.win_updates` is not a role, it's a module, so it cannot be used in `roles`, it belongs to `tasks`.